# Right way to send data to nested custom input component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am on migrating to Vue from React, and I just liked the `v-model` thing Vue offers. Now I am in a situation and not able to find out what is the vue-ish way of doing this.

Here is how my component tree looks like:

```
- FormContainer
  -FormView
    - CustomInput
      - input
```

I have my states in `FormContainer` let's call it name and age. I want to **avoid writing custom setter methods** as I usually do using `v-model`, how can I go about passing the data down to the input component.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
// in my container
<form-view :name="name" :age="age" />

// in my form view I am doing something like
<custom-input v-model="age"/>
<input v-model="name" />
```

both of them do not work and I get the following error `Avoid mutating a prop directly`

I should be able to do something like

```
<form-view @age="age" :age="age" @name="name" :name="name"/>
```

or something similar. Please let me know if you need more details on this.

Comment: I'm quite new to Vue myself, but the @ symbol is supposed to be a shortcut for v-on: - are you sure you are using it correctly here? To pass variables down to the lower components, you use bind to assign to the props variables in the Vue component. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Composing-with-Components

Comment: Ya that is just a thought, I'm not using it that way. I will update my question with what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered this question twice already, and though my answers had merit, I don't think they were quite on-target for your question, so I've deleted them.

Fundamentally, you want events to "bubble up" from the elements where the events are happening to the Vue that owns the data items. Vue events don't bubble, but native events do, so if you have a native `input` event being generated at the bottom of a hierarchy, you can catch it with [`@input.native`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) in any component up the tree from there.

For the example you gave, if the `name` and `age` data items live in the top-level Vue, the outermost component can take them as props with the [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier). That means that any `update:name` and `update:age` events from the component will result in the data items being updated. So far so good.

Moving inside the `form-view` component, we have a native input element. Normally, it emits native `input` events. We want those to bubble up as `update:name` events, so we handle that like so:

```
 <input :value="name" @input="$emit('update:name', $event.target.value)">
```

Now here's the fun part: inside the `form-view` component, we have the `custom-input` component. Somewhere in its heart (and we don't really care how far down that might be), it generates a native input event. Instead of catching that at each level and bubbling it up, we can let it bubble up naturally and catch it at the root of the `custom-input` component, and emit the required `update:age` event:

```
<custom-input :value="age" @input.native="$emit('update:age', $event.target.value)">
```

Putting it all together, we have two variables that are passed through components to `input` elements, two `input` event handlers, and no computeds.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Jerry',
    age: 21
  },
  components: {
    formView: {
      props: ['age', 'name'],
      components: {
        customInput: {
          props: ['value']
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>Name: {{name}}</div>
  <div>Age: {{age}}</div>
  <form-view :name.sync="name" :age.sync="age" inline-template>
    <div>
      <custom-input :value="age" @input.native="$emit('update:age', $event.target.value)" inline-template>
        <div>
          Age: <input :value="value">
        </div>
      </custom-input>
      <div>Name: <input :value="name" @input="$emit('update:name', $event.target.value)"></div>
    </div>
  </form-view>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: A small addition. Passing an object in props is by reference, so if you set up a computed setter, you can modify the props variable directly from there. Perhaps not the best way of doing it, but thought it might be a noteworthy addition.